# redirecting log4j messages from a method to a different log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Right now i use log4j in its plain vanilla/out-of-the-box form. I've a log4j.properties file in the class path and various logger messages littered across the web application. Now i'm interested in redirecting log messages from a method "abc" in package "xyz" to go to a specific log file "pqr". I dont want all the logger messages from package xyz to go to "pqr" but just from that one method ("abc") in the package.

How do i achieve this?

TIA
Bo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the config file I'm using. This will send some specific messages to a file and others to the console. This may help you a little bit hopefully.
This is used in a standalone aplication.

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
<!-- ============================== -->
<!-- Append SQL messages to a file. -->
<!-- ============================== -->
<appender name="SQL" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE" />
    <param name="File" value="sql-statement.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- ============================== -->
<!-- Append messages to the console -->
<!-- ============================== -->
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- =============================== -->
<!-- Application specific categories -->
<!-- =============================== -->
<category name="com.edusoft.crashtest.qsbi">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</category>
<category name="com.edusoft.crashtest.qsbi.printer" additivity="true">
    <priority value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="SQL" />
</category>

<!-- Setup the Root category -->
<root>
    <priority value="ERROR" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be that granular. Why not pull that method out to a separate class?

Comment: Good idea. But this is what am trying to do, i created one more logger in the properties file and use that logger in the method (basically declare two logger objects at the class level) and all the messages from this method are being redirected to this new & separate logger. Something like this:

Comment: oops pressed enter accidentally.

Comment: private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
 private static Logger logger2 = Logger.getLogger("AUDITLOG");
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        logger.info("TESTS");
        logger2.info("SDSDS");
        System.out.println("ding dong");

Comment: @BoCode: So, is it working as expected? And please add this code and your configuration to your question. This might get more people to answer your question.